# Laravel migration build as couple of one to many relation

Tags: laravel, migration

I try to adjust two of one to many relation by below migration code.

Jobs table has relations to Customers and Users tables as many to one relation.

But there was occured errors as below.

***1) Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'time_end'***

***2) errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"***

After error, I modified how value type changed timestamp to datetime and deleted customer_id foreign key. then no errors with migration table created successfully sign.

Basically I wish to calculate used time with time_start(from created_at datetime) and time_end(now() methods or Carbon) for get the time_end, so this is also problem. I need your kindness help. thanks

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateJobsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('job_type');
            $table->text('note_1');
            $table->timestamp('time_start');
            $table->timestamp('time_end');
            $table->timestamp('time_used');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
             ->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')
             ->on('customers')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('jobs');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add `->nullable()` to the timestamp columns for the default value error to go away. As for the other issue, do you have the `users` and `customers` tables created already?

Comment: @A3mercury, yes I made it. used by Infyom:generator. Have you any another advice? thanks :)